# How to unite two different filter commands in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, filter

For example, I have the following JSON code which contains multiple objects:

```
[
  {
    "average": 6.04,
    "date": "2021-03-01",
    "highest": 6.08,
    "lowest": 5.99,
    "order_count": 2345,
    "volume": 3599480071
  },
  {
    "average": 5.97,
    "date": "2021-03-02",
    "highest": 6.05,
    "lowest": 5.85,
    "order_count": 2335,
    "volume": 5211678303
  },
  {
    "average": 5.96,
    "date": "2021-03-03",
    "highest": 5.97,
    "lowest": 5.75,
    "order_count": 2268,
    "volume": 3900129438
  },
  {
    "average": 5.96,
    "date": "2021-03-04",
    "highest": 6.01,
    "lowest": 5.76,
    "order_count": 2142,
    "volume": 4151340967
  },
  {
    "average": 5.94,
    "date": "2021-03-05",
    "highest": 5.99,
    "lowest": 5.72,
    "order_count": 2279,
    "volume": 4695138563
  },
  {
    "average": 5.95,
    "date": "2021-03-06",
    "highest": 5.99,
    "lowest": 5.76,
    "order_count": 2598,
    "volume": 6298670176
  },
  {
    "average": 6.01,
    "date": "2021-03-07",
    "highest": 6.05,
    "lowest": 5.91,
    "order_count": 2832,
    "volume": 4787097077
  },
  {
    "average": 5.87,
    "date": "2021-03-08",
    "highest": 6.03,
    "lowest": 5.74,
    "order_count": 2462,
    "volume": 5340747843
  },
  {
    "average": 5.9,
    "date": "2021-03-09",
    "highest": 5.99,
    "lowest": 5.67,
    "order_count": 2176,
    "volume": 5361380021
  },
  {
    "average": 5.9,
    "date": "2021-03-10",
    "highest": 6,
    "lowest": 5.63,
    "order_count": 2353,
    "volume": 5791738338
  },
  {
    "average": 5.92,
    "date": "2021-03-11",
    "highest": 6.02,
    "lowest": 5.71,
    "order_count": 2332,
    "volume": 4334212610
  },
  {
    "average": 5.97,
    "date": "2021-03-12",
    "highest": 5.99,
    "lowest": 5.91,
    "order_count": 2097,
    "volume": 3765328306
  },
  {
    "average": 5.93,
    "date": "2021-03-13",
    "highest": 5.98,
    "lowest": 5.8,
    "order_count": 2482,
    "volume": 6257745118
  },
  {
    "average": 5.78,
    "date": "2021-03-14",
    "highest": 5.84,
    "lowest": 5.61,
    "order_count": 2803,
    "volume": 7301956471
  }
]
```

and I need to filter this array by 2 parameters at the same time:

a) I need to keep only last 7 objects in the array-i need the statistical data for the last week only, ignoring all the previous records. The most fresh updates are always in the end of array, so this will be most simple and fast way to filter it by date in my case;

b) I only need to keep the raws "average", "date" and "volume", with the corresponding numbers, in the each object.

So, if take the example JSON code as an input, this is what I want to see after the filtering:

```
[
  {
    "average": 5.87,
    "date": "2021-03-08",
    "volume": 5340747843
  },
  {
    "average": 5.9,
    "date": "2021-03-09",
    "volume": 5361380021
  },
  {
    "average": 5.9,
    "date": "2021-03-10",
    "volume": 5791738338
  },
  {
    "average": 5.92,
    "date": "2021-03-11",
    "volume": 4334212610
  },
  {
    "average": 5.97,
    "date": "2021-03-12",
    "volume": 3765328306
  },
  {
    "average": 5.93,
    "date": "2021-03-13",
    "volume": 6257745118
  },
  {
    "average": 5.78,
    "date": "2021-03-14",
    "volume": 7301956471
  }
]
```

I don't know, how can I make the a) part of the filtering, but after searching in similar topics, I know that I can make the b) part of filtering using the Array.prototype.filter, something like that:

```
var array2 = stat.filter(function (el) {
  return el.average >= 0 &&
         el.date >= 0 &&
         el.volume >=0 &&
         el.num_of_baths >= 0;
});
```

How can I make the a) filtering, and what will be the most effective way to combine the a) and the b) filtering in my situation? Thanks!

Comment: So you want last 7 entries, then filter non zero ones?

Comment: Yes, only 7 last entries are important for me

Comment: Okay, but then you want to filter non-zero values for the last 7 days?

Comment: Exactly-at first get rid of the everything apart last 7 days data, and then filter the remaining info to get rid of raws I do not need. Thank you so much for showing me how to stick to date instead of hardcoded slice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could slice the array from the end and pick only the wanted properties.

```js
const
    array = [{ average: 6.04, date: "2021-03-01", highest: 6.08, lowest: 5.99, order_count: 2345, volume: 3599480071 }, { average: 5.97, date: "2021-03-02", highest: 6.05, lowest: 5.85, order_count: 2335, volume: 5211678303 }, { average: 5.96, date: "2021-03-03", highest: 5.97, lowest: 5.75, order_count: 2268, volume: 3900129438 }, { average: 5.96, date: "2021-03-04", highest: 6.01, lowest: 5.76, order_count: 2142, volume: 4151340967 }, { average: 5.94, date: "2021-03-05", highest: 5.99, lowest: 5.72, order_count: 2279, volume: 4695138563 }, { average: 5.95, date: "2021-03-06", highest: 5.99, lowest: 5.76, order_count: 2598, volume: 6298670176 }, { average: 6.01, date: "2021-03-07", highest: 6.05, lowest: 5.91, order_count: 2832, volume: 4787097077 }, { average: 5.87, date: "2021-03-08", highest: 6.03, lowest: 5.74, order_count: 2462, volume: 5340747843 }, { average: 5.9, date: "2021-03-09", highest: 5.99, lowest: 5.67, order_count: 2176, volume: 5361380021 }, { average: 5.9, date: "2021-03-10", highest: 6, lowest: 5.63, order_count: 2353, volume: 5791738338 }, { average: 5.92, date: "2021-03-11", highest: 6.02, lowest: 5.71, order_count: 2332, volume: 4334212610 }, { average: 5.97, date: "2021-03-12", highest: 5.99, lowest: 5.91, order_count: 2097, volume: 3765328306 }, { average: 5.93, date: "2021-03-13", highest: 5.98, lowest: 5.8, order_count: 2482, volume: 6257745118 }, { average: 5.78, date: "2021-03-14", highest: 5.84, lowest: 5.61, order_count: 2803, volume: 7301956471 }]
    result = array
        .slice(-7)
        .map(({ average, date, volume }) => ({ average, date, volume }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a good candidate for `reduce`.

You can loop the data only once and reduce it based on the filters and the desired structure.

**example:**

```js
const data = [{ average: 6.04, date: "2021-03-01", highest: 6.08, lowest: 5.99, order_count: 2345, volume: 3599480071 }, { average: 5.97, date: "2021-03-02", highest: 6.05, lowest: 5.85, order_count: 2335, volume: 5211678303 }, { average: 5.96, date: "2021-03-03", highest: 5.97, lowest: 5.75, order_count: 2268, volume: 3900129438 }, { average: 5.96, date: "2021-03-04", highest: 6.01, lowest: 5.76, order_count: 2142, volume: 4151340967 }, { average: 5.94, date: "2021-03-05", highest: 5.99, lowest: 5.72, order_count: 2279, volume: 4695138563 }, { average: 5.95, date: "2021-03-06", highest: 5.99, lowest: 5.76, order_count: 2598, volume: 6298670176 }, { average: 6.01, date: "2021-03-07", highest: 6.05, lowest: 5.91, order_count: 2832, volume: 4787097077 }, { average: 5.87, date: "2021-03-08", highest: 6.03, lowest: 5.74, order_count: 2462, volume: 5340747843 }, { average: 5.9, date: "2021-03-09", highest: 5.99, lowest: 5.67, order_count: 2176, volume: 5361380021 }, { average: 5.9, date: "2021-03-10", highest: 6, lowest: 5.63, order_count: 2353, volume: 5791738338 }, { average: 5.92, date: "2021-03-11", highest: 6.02, lowest: 5.71, order_count: 2332, volume: 4334212610 }, { average: 5.97, date: "2021-03-12", highest: 5.99, lowest: 5.91, order_count: 2097, volume: 3765328306 }, { average: 5.93, date: "2021-03-13", highest: 5.98, lowest: 5.8, order_count: 2482, volume: 6257745118 }, { average: 5.78, date: "2021-03-14", highest: 5.84, lowest: 5.61, order_count: 2803, volume: 7301956471 }];

const startOfLastWeek = new Date(
    new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
).getTime();

function filterLastWeek(element) {
    return (new Date(element.date).getTime() >= startOfLastWeek);
}

function filterZeroValues(element) {
    return (
        element.average >= 0 &&
        element.volume >= 0 &&
        element.date !== ""
    );
}

const result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (filterZeroValues(curr) && filterLastWeek(curr))
        acc.push({
            average: curr.average,
            date: curr.date,
            volume: curr.volume,
        });
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Also you can adjust date range by editing `startOfLastWeek` to avoid hardcoded `splice`.